# How to use RestClient with Oauth 2.0 and Client + TLS certificates?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, ssl, oauth-2.0, restsharp

I'm new to OAuth2.0 and all certificate stuff so please spare me ;-)

Today i'm trying to interface with a REST API of a Bank. They provide a good explanations, found here https://developer.ing.com/openbanking/get-started however these are all written for web-development (i think) and all the OAuth stuff is somewhat new for me. I've create a new test app that should connect to a Sandbox environment of the bank. However it's unclear for me where to put the certificates. I have four files; Client certificate + Key and TLS certificate + key. Besides this i've registrerd my application and received a ClientID. However when testing with the Sandbox environment they provide a ClientID for public use (same as the certificates)

This is the code i've got so far:

```
'Example: https://developer.ing.com/openbanking/get-started
'OAuth2.0 explained: https://developer.ing.com/api-marketplace/marketplace/2d00fd5f-88cd-4416-bbca-f309ebb03bfe/documentation#introduction

'Create New RestClient
Dim ClientIDSandBox As String = "e77d776b-90af-4684-bebc-521e5b2614dd"
Dim client As New RestClient("https://api.sandbox.ing.com/")

'Some code i found here: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/139799/call-to-tls-1-2-server-with-restsharp-works-in-console-app-not-in-xamarin-forms
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 9999
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
client.Proxy = New WebProxy

'Create new certificate collection containing the Client and TLS certificate
Dim certColl As New X509CertificateCollection
certColl.Add(New X509Certificate("../../ING/Sandbox/example_client_tls.cer")) 'A TLS connection certificate used for setting up a mutual TLS connection
certColl.Add(New X509Certificate("../../ING/Sandbox/example_client_signing.cer")) 'A HTTP Signature certificate used for signing the token request in accordance with the Signature Header RFC
client.ClientCertificates = certColl

'Create new request
Dim request As New RestRequest("/oauth2/token", DataFormat.None)

'Add custom headers to request
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
request.AddHeader("Date", Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString("r"))
request.AddHeader("Digest", "SHA-256=47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=")
request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Signature keyId={ClientIDSandBox}, algorithm=""rsa-sha256"", headers=""(request-target) Date digest"", signature=""{File.ReadAllText("../../ING/Sandbox/example_client_signing.cer")}""")
request.AddParameter("grant_type=client_credentials&scope=greetings%3view", ParameterType.RequestBody)

'POST the request and retrieve the server response
Dim response As IRestResponse = client.Post(request)

'Printout the response
Debug.Print(response.ErrorMessage)
Debug.Print(response.StatusCode.ToString)
Debug.Print(response.Content)
```

When i use this i get a error back: `Specified value contains invalid CRLF characters. Parameter name: value`

Comment: I'm no expert in OAuth, but without entering into details, have you discarded the most stupid reasons? Like a copy/paste of code having CRLF chars, etc? Maybe you can give everything a quick look with a simple tool like Notepad++ having enabled the "Show all characters" option.

Comment: Thanks for your simpel but yet easily made mistake. I checked everything multiple times and all is as it should. I gues im missing something where the package must be signed or something....

Comment: Have you tried taking the data that you are loading using filenames and also using File.ReadAllText and just pasting it directly into the app and see if it works, and exclude the possibility that there could be a trailing linefeed in a file?

Comment: Yep doesn't work. I figured out that i need to sign the request with SHA256 and base64 but this is somewhat new for me and googling around for examples with RestClient i discovered not may people are doing this yet because it's a high level of Oauth

Answer (score 0):

try this
Replace

```
request.AddParameter("grant_type=client_credentials&scope=greetings%3view", ParameterType.RequestBody)
```

with

```
request.AddBody("grant_type=client_credentials&scope=greetings%3view", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
```